# Wicket + websocket page not refreshing because CSRF attack

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, wicket

In my application I need to use websocket. I follow [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_how_to_use) example so in my wicket application I got:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean wicketFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean wicketFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    wicketFilter.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.FORWARD,
            DispatcherType.ASYNC);
    wicketFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
    wicketFilter.setFilter(new JavaxWebSocketFilter());
    wicketFilter.addInitParameter(WicketFilter.APP_FACT_PARAM, SpringWebApplicationFactory.class.getName());
    wicketFilter.addInitParameter(WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
    wicketFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return wicketFilter;
}

@Bean
public WicketServerEndpointConfig wicketServerEndpointConfig() {
    return new WicketServerEndpointConfig();
}
```

and in page I add behavior:

```
private void addWebSocketUpdating() {
    add(new WebSocketBehavior() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onConnect(ConnectedMessage message) {
            super.onConnect(message);

            webSocketService.addClient(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPush(WebSocketRequestHandler handler, IWebSocketPushMessage message) {
            super.onPush(handler, message);

            if (message instanceof WSMessage) {
                WSMessage msg = (WSMessage) message;
                if (msg.isAdd()) {
                    model.getObject().getPickupFindingParticipants().add(msg.getParticipant());
                } else if (msg.isDelete()) {
                    model.getObject().getPickupFindingParticipants().remove(msg.getParticipant());
                }
            }
            handler.add(PickupFindPage.this);
        }
    });
}
```

add logic

```
public void addParticipant(PickupParticipantDto participant) {
    if (null != broadcaster) {
        WSMessage message = new WSMessage(participant);
        message.setAdd(true);

        broadcaster.broadcastAll(connections.listIterator().next().getApplication(), message);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("WebSockets can not send message");
    }
}
```

but when page should be refresh I got warning in log:

```
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-1] INFO  o.a.w.p.h.CsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener Possible CSRF attack, request URL: ws://localhost:7002/wicket/websocket?pageId=5&wicket-ajax-baseurl=pickup%2F19%2Ffind%3F5&wicket-app-name=javaxWebSocketFilter, Origin: null, action: allowed
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-1] INFO  o.a.w.p.h.CsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener Possible CSRF attack, request URL: ws://localhost:7002/wicket/websocket?pageId=5&wicket-ajax-baseurl=pickup%2F19%2Ffind%3F5&wicket-app-name=javaxWebSocketFilter, Origin: null, action: allowed
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-0] INFO  o.a.w.p.h.CsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener Possible CSRF attack, request URL: ws://localhost:7002/wicket/websocket?pageId=7&wicket-ajax-baseurl=pickup%2F19%2Ffind%3F7&wicket-app-name=javaxWebSocketFilter, Origin: null, action: allowed
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-0] INFO  o.a.w.p.h.CsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener Possible CSRF attack, request URL: ws://localhost:7002/wicket/websocket?pageId=7&wicket-ajax-baseurl=pickup%2F19%2Ffind%3F7&wicket-app-name=javaxWebSocketFilter, Origin: null, action: allowed
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-1] WARN  o.a.wicket.page.PartialPageUpdate Component '[Page class = org.tomass.dota.rattlebot.web.pages.tournament.pickup.PickupFindPage, id = 5, render count = 1]' not rendered because it was already removed from page
2021-11-25 00:23:55.635 [Wicket-WebSocket-HttpRequest-Thread-0] WARN  o.a.wicket.page.PartialPageUpdate Component '[Page class = org.tomass.dota.rattlebot.web.pages.tournament.pickup.PickupFindPage, id = 7, render count = 1]' not rendered because it was already removed from page
```

and advice what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `WebSocketAwareCsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener` instead of `CsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener` in YourApplication#init().

See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/3a74b2dc9fd51692faf146f68e215670f994b5ae/wicket-native-websocket/wicket-native-websocket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/ws/WebSocketAwareCsrfPreventionRequestCycleListener.java#L24-L31